# Error when attempting to bevel edges

Tags: bevel

I have been trying to round bevel the edges highlighted in yellow & I have not been able to. The problem seems to be arising since I added the tube (highlighted in red). After the addition of this piece Blender is now creating all sorts of weird shapes when I try to bevel this face as a surface.

Can someone please offer some assistance?

Kind regards,
Jake

[image]

Some explanation of what I am trying to achieve:

This is going to be an oil tank for a vintage motorcycle that I own & may plan is to print the model and then cast it using lost PLA.

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded the file. I am trying to create a round radius of approx 5mm diameter on all edges except the spout. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=aVPsEsV4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/aVPsEsV4/)

Comment: First thing apply the Scale of your object (Ctrl A). The Bevel modifier doesn't work because the Clamp Overlap option of the Bevel modifier is on, which prevents the bevel to make some faces overlap. You could use the Limit Method > Weight option, it will work for a 5 mm bevel. If you want a larger bevel you need to check where the problem is, where the faces are overlapping when you bevel. Or redo the topology from scratch